# Javascript add class if localStorage value exists without reloading page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, local-storage

I work on ionic 5 and angular and I need to change the DOM of my view after a modal popup.
The problem is that I have to reload the view to see the DOM modifications, and I need it to change without any reload.

**First step** = add key and value in LocalStorage and modal appears on element click.

**Second step** = I need a addCLass('hide') on divs when modal is dismiss.

Any tips to make these changes without reloading the page ?

HTML code :

```
    <div class="circleImgContainer">
  <img class="suivezLaRecoImg" src="../assets/imgs/muscu_cardio/circleRecommandation@2x.png" alt="">
  <img class="demarrerVosRepImg hide" (click)="goReps()" src="../assets/imgs/muscu_cardio/demarrerVosReps@2x.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Ts :

```
  ngOnInit() {
let content = document.querySelector(".circleImgContainer");

if (localStorage.getItem('serie_1') == 'true') {
  content.classList.add('hide');
}
```

}

Comment: I don't know if I understood this correctly: Why don't you bind it to another click event of the modal. For example when it's dismissed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in this case you can use `setInterval` to always check if a `localStorage` has the desired value and change page content without having to reload.

Here's an example below, normally you can provide `setInterval` with a time (in milliseconds) interval, but without, it will always constantly update if the `if` statement matches your set condition.

```
setInterval(() => {

  ngOnInit() {
    let content = document.querySelector(".circleImgContainer");

    if (localStorage.getItem('serie_1') == 'true') {
      content.classList.add('hide');
    }
  }

})
```

Comment: I binded the changes on another click, waiting to find a cleaner solution. The use of setInterval could work I guess, I didn't think about it, very good idea ! Thanks a lot.